# python nested list Error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'beer'

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm am trying to iterate through a nested list of lists and append to the list

```
    # def get_info(item_urls, count): #count is being passed in
    # for item in item_urls:
        #get data from current URL

        resp = s.get(url1, headers=headers, verify=False).text
        soup = bs(resp, 'html.parser')
        res = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'table table-striped-odd specification'})
        first = res[0]
        res1 = first.find_all('td')
        print(res1)
        for thing in res1:
            print(thing.text)
        table = [[] for i in range(0, count)]
        for thing in res1:
            # print(thing.text)
            table.append(thing.text)
            print(table)
```

sorry, I should have given real code. this is my response:

```
Processor Type
1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology
Hard Drive Capacity
256 GB
Condition
New
Processor Speed
1 GHz
Manufacturer Part Number
8BD79UA#ABA
Wireless Technology
Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo (MU-MIMO supported)
RAM Memory
8 GB
Maximum RAM Supported
8 GB
Operating System
Windows 10
Model
14-dq1039wm
Screen Size
14"
Brand
HP
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA', 'Wireless Technology']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA', 'Wireless Technology', 'Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo (MU-MIMO supported)']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA', 'Wireless Technology', 'Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo (MU-MIMO supported)', 'RAM Memory']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA', 'Wireless Technology', 'Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo (MU-MIMO supported)', 'RAM Memory', '8 GB']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 'Processor Type', '1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology', 'Hard Drive Capacity', '256 GB', 'Condition', 'New', 'Processor Speed', '1 GHz', 'Manufacturer Part Number', '8BD79UA#ABA', 'Wireless Technology', 'Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo (MU-MIMO supported)', 'RAM Memory', '8 GB', 'Maximum RAM Supported']
```

I would like to iterate through data and append it to a nested table, then return the table

I'm not sure why my list is is not

Comment: What is the desired output? Can you show what you would like `table` to look like at the end?

Comment: `for i in data:` make `i` the strings in data, which you are trying to turn into integers -- `int('beer')` sounds delicious, but probably isn't a valid number.

Comment: You cannot apply int() to a string, its argument should be float. What resul;t do you expect from int(i)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, IIUC

```
data = ["beer", "is", "awesome!", "...", "for", "helping", "my", "depression"]
count = len(data) # counting data for a number... that I should have just made up
table = []
for i in data:
    print(i)
    table.append([i])
    print(i, table)
for thing in table:
    print(thing)
```